# angular-dimple dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, dimple.js

I want to use "angular-dimple" library in my app, and the dependency injection isn't working. In the [homepage of the library](http://esripdx.github.io/angular-dimple/), they say I just need d3 and dimple links included in the html  and just include 'angular-dimple' as a dependency in my module declaration. The thing is that doesn't work, as I get this error:

"...Module 'angular-dimple' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

My angular module declaration and html headers are as follows:

```js
var smsApp = angular.module('smsApp', ['angular-dimple', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
        <title>Solidarity Message Service</title>
        
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sms-blaster.css">
              
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
      
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        
        
        <script src="angular-1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
        
        <script src="angular-plugins/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Dimple graphics dependencies-->
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.6.min.js"></script>
        
        <script src="javascripts/sms-blaster.js"></script>
 
    </head>
```

What am I missing here??

P.S.: I have already tried putting d3 and dimple script links before angular in the html , and I've swapped the priority in which I'm refering angular-dimple and ui-bootstrap in the dependency array of angular.module.

Comment: You have missed to inject angular-dimple.js file in your html file. [Here is the documentation for using angular-dimple library](http://esripdx.github.io/angular-dimple/) which works above d3.js and dimple.js, in this documentation below steps are given to use this library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like the library is missing from your HTML. add angular-dimple.js (after the Angular import)

`<script src="../assets/js/lib/angular-dimple.js"></script>`

Comment: This is embarrassing. So frustrating to miss the most obvious. Thanks both of you, Varsha and Eran